# Custom anchors in Yolov3

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, object-detection, yolo

I'm training an object detector using Yolov3 on my custom dataset. Traditionally in Yolo you have a variety of object classes so you get a good mix of anchors. In my case, I only have one object class and it has pretty similar dimensions. So when I cluster the dimensions using K-means, I get 9 anchors of pretty similar size... which seems counterproductive.

In fact, I tried with some random anchor sizes that are not all similar and got better results than with 9 similar anchors. So I wonder, what's the best strategy for anchors for 1 class object detector?

Answer (score 1):

This is what author says about anchor boxes [here](https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet#how-to-improve-object-detection):

> Only if you are an expert in neural detection networks - recalculate
> anchors for your dataset for width and height from cfg-file:
> darknet.exe detector calc_anchors data/obj.data -num_of_clusters 9
> -width 416 -height 416 then set the same 9 anchors in each of 3 [yolo]-layers in your cfg-file. But you should change indexes of
> anchors masks= for each [yolo]-layer, so for `YOLOv4` the
> 1st-[yolo]-layer has anchors smaller than **30x30**, 2nd smaller than
> **60x60**, 3rd remaining, and vice versa for `YOLOv3`. Also you should
> change the filters=(classes + 5)* before each
> [yolo]-layer. **If many of the calculated anchors do not fit under the
> appropriate layers - then just try using all the default anchors.**

So to train single class object detector where in object dimensions are pretty similar, then:

1. Use **default** anchor boxes as stated above
2. Use **`random=0`** in the `cfg`

To understand anchor box concept, go through [this](https://github.com/pjreddie/darknet/issues/568) discussion.

Also since [Yolov4](https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet/blob/master/cfg/yolov4-custom.cfg) is available now, suggest you to use that for better `accuracy`/`mAP`. If you want to stick to `Yolov3`, use [**Yolov3-spp**](https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet/blob/master/cfg/yolov3-spp.cfg) or [**Yolov3_5l**](https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet/blob/master/cfg/yolov3_5l.cfg) for improved results.

Comment: Thanks, I'm actually using a custom Keras implementation of Yolov3. I tried with default anchors but they don't work as well.

Comment: @MikeAzatov I see! When it comes to Keras Yolov3, I have  used this [repo](https://github.com/experiencor/keras-yolo3). For me both default anchors and generated anchors have worked well, but it was for multiple classes, haven't tried single class detector with this repo though. For single class have used this [repo](https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet) and has worked well with default anchors.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I'm using this one: https://github.com/qqwweee/keras-yolo3. I'm getting decent results but just wanted to get optimal. Currently trying to figure out Yolov4. Do you know of a good repo? Preferable in Keras?

Comment: Ah okay! only Keras repo that I came across for `Yolov4` is [this](https://github.com/david8862/keras-YOLOv3-model-set) one. If you're okay to not use `Keras`  then the repo I have mentioned earlier is the best one in terms of flexibility, features and support

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a shot. I struggled to get the official tensorlfow implementation of Yolov4 to work thus far.